# TypeScript complains: Cannot find name 'Notification'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, typescript-typings

I am using VS 2017 and TS 2.2.1

I am getting compilation error: Cannot find name 'Notification'.

When I try to declare the Notification, TS complains that it is already declared in packages\Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild.2.2.1\tools\tsc. Indeed, it is there defined as:

```
declare var Notification: {
    prototype: Notification;
    new(title: string, options?: NotificationOptions): Notification;
    requestPermission(callback?: NotificationPermissionCallback): Promise<string>;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using that has the compilation error?

Comment: Have you installed npm? in wich OS are you working? Win? Linux?

Comment: Did you installed from here? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55258

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by upgrading TypeScript from 1.7.5 to 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Might there be competing TypeScript versions installed on the machine?

Check the versions installed on your machine.

[image: TypeScript VS Installation Folder]

Now go to the Visual Studio Installer and see if there's multiple TypeScript versions installed. Uninstall 2.1 if you find it?

[image: Visual Studio Code Installer]

Restart Visual Studio Code and see what happens?

**Update**: You could check in Visual Studio Code to make sure it's using the correct version, and what is installed. Open a TypeScript file, go to the bottom and click the TypeScript version number:

[image: Select TypeScript version]

See Visual Studio Code active version:

[image: Visual Studio Code version]

Comment: I only have version 2.2 and it's doing the same thing.

Comment: Do you have any other versions of TypeScript installed? 1.8? Check Visual Studio Code's running version, I've updated my answer

Comment: Scratch that. I was having a different problem. Though I thought we were working in Visual Studio, not VS Code?

Comment: No it's me, I'm getting confused. I use both, but have had the same problem in Visual Studio Code.